# Magento2: How to setTaxClassId as 0

Tags: magento2

We tried using event method "sales_quote_collect_totals_after"

```
$quote = $observer->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
            $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
            $product->setTaxClassId(0); // tax class removed.now the price is with no 
            $logger->info('tax'.$product->getTaxClassId()); // Simple Text Log


        }
```

We got the log of tax class id as 0 but in frontend taking the actual product rule

Advanced thanks

Comment: Use `$product->save()` and check it.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you should do it:

Create a plugin in your custom package by adding the line:

> app/code/Vendor/Package/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
    <plugin name="interceptAddingProductToCart" type="Vendor\Package\Model\Checkout\Cart\Plugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

create file:

> app/code/Vendor/Package/Model/Checkout/Cart/Plugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package\Model\Checkout\Cart;

class Plugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    protected $quote;

    /**
     * Plugin constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
    }

    public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {
            $productInfo->setTaxClassId(0);

        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
    }
}
```

or download my module for you, via this link :

https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/832614/B0GgqxJ8bSaLcXKd/AlekseiBoltinov1.zip

Comment: I need after change the zipcode then only we update the taxclass id